# How to add fixed search bar in angular mat select

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 8 and I implement filter in dropdown fields. But I don't know how can I fix the search bar at the top of the mat select.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-2ngntr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Html

```
<h4>mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
     <input (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)"> 
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of selectedStates" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Ts

```
states: string[] = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
    'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
    'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
    'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
    'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania',
    'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
  ];


selectedStates = this.states; 


onKey(value) { 
this.selectedStates = this.search(value);
}
```

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples Refer this doc

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngx-mat-select-search package to achieve the same:

First Install:

```
npm install ngx-mat-select-search
```

In app.module.ts:

```
import { NgxMatSelectSearchModule } from 'ngx-mat-select-search';
and in imports array:

imports: [
   ....,
   NgxMatSelectSearchModule 
]
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="control" ngDefaultControl placeholder="Tags" #Select>
        <ngx-mat-select-search [placeholderLabel]="'Search Item'" [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'No matching records found'" [formControl]="control"
         ngDefaultControl></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <mat-option class="m-t" *ngFor="let obj of filteredRecords | async" [value]="obj">
            {{obj}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

[CheckThisSample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search-uyecug)